# Parse error: parse error in /Library/WebServer/Documents/website/includes/config.php on line 4

Tags: php, parsing, osx-elcapitan, require-once

Since installing Mac OSX El Capitain, I am getting a parse error. The code works fine on the server, but on my development workstation, I get this error consistently.

Parse error: parse error in /Library/WebServer/Documents/website/includes/config.php on line 4

```
// Calling code snippet:

include("includes/navbar.php");
require_once("includes/config.php");

$servername = DBHOST;
$username = DBUSER;
$password = DBPASS;
$database = DBNAME;
```

config.php file:

```php
<?php
/* Config File for Common Values */

define ("DBHOST", “127.0.0.1:3306”);  <--- This is line 4
define ("DBUSER", “userid”);
define ("DBPASS", “password”);
define ("DBNAME", “database”);

?>
```

Comment: that's what happens when you code with a Word Processing app, rather than a code editor.

Comment: *"<--- This is line 4"*, and 5, and 6, and 7.

Comment: @sa-7 that pending edit of yours http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10175384 clearly is changing code. DON'T do that. If the OP's using that, then that's the problem and an answer was given based on it. You can modify tags, spelling etc. but NOT code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using smart quotes (`“` and `”`) where you should have straight quotes (`"`). Replace the smart quotes with straight quotes. For example, change

```
“127.0.0.1:3306”
```

to

```
"127.0.0.1:3306"
```

Do the same with each of the other `define()` statements.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for catching that. That would have made my answer look pretty odd and probably really confused OP!

Comment: You're welcome Ed. Yeah... and someone might've downvoted you because of it. How many times I've seen that happen before, and for myself also.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah, I've been a victim of that, too. No good deed goes unpunished, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and sorry about the malformed post. Was my first here.

Comment: @Just4Fun Glad to help! Please remember to select an answer! :)

Comment: Done. The resolution worked perfectly. Thanks again!